# Html5, css3, javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<?php include'header.php'; ?>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="login-section">
  <p>Allready a member? <a href="#">Login</a> </p>
  <div class="login-form">
   <p class="title">Become a member</p>
   <p>I am</p>
   <div class="input-type">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Buyer/Ownder" checked> Buyer/Ownder
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Developer/Agent" > Developer/Agent
    </div>

    <!-- this form is for buyer -->
   <form action="" class="form-group">
    
    
    <div class="input-type">
    <label for="email">Your Name</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="type your email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="input-type">
     <label for="password">Your Email</label>
     <input type="password" placeholder="type your password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">
   </form>
   <!-- this form is for buyer  end -->



   <!-- this from is for agent -->
   <form action="">
    <div class="input-type">
    <label for="email">Your Company Name</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="type your email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="input-type">
     <label for="password">Your Email</label>
     <input type="password" placeholder="type your password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">
   </form>
   <!-- this from is for agent  end-->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>

<?php include'footer.php'; ?>
```

[1, There are two buttons. There are specific form for each button. When clicked one, a specific form is visible. How can i do that in html using javascript or jquery, is possible boostrap or css?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9nhX.png)

See the code, here are two forms for buyer and agent. and i added two radio button for that. I want to show these from individually when specific button is clicked without breaking my layout.

Comment: Titles are for titles, not tags. Questions are for text, code, etc, not a link to an image. Please read [ask]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and consider reviewing [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands this question is very broad and demonstrates no effort on your part to do research or attempt any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
 // on page load
 $( "#buyerForm" ).show();
 $( "#developperForm" ).hide();
 // radio button actions
 $( "#buyerButton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#buyerForm" ).toggle();
  $( "#developperForm" ).toggle();
});
 $( "#developperButton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#buyerForm" ).toggle();
  $( "#developperForm" ).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot,